# Unable to click option in dropdown list selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I tried using the Select module, but when I do the Element is either not interactable or it is "not visible". Here are the relevant codes.

HTML

```
    < head >
    < script >

        function onChangeCardType() {
            var value = $('#card_type').val();
            $('#img_' + value).siblings().hide();
            $('#img_' + value).show();
        }

    </script>

</head>

<body>
    <table>
        <thead>

            <tr>
                <th align="left">Card type</th>
                <td colspan="2" style="font-size:12px;">
                    <select name="requestDTO.vpc_card" id="card_type" onchange="onChangeCardType()"
                            class="select required"
                            style="width: 342px; font-size:12px;">
                        <option value="Amex" >American Express</option>
                        <option value="Mastercard" >MasterCard</option>
                        <option value="Visa" >Visa</option>
                        <option value="JCB" >JCB</option>
                    </select>
                    <a class="ui-selectmenu ui-widget ui-state-default select required ui-selectmenu-dropdown ui-corner-all" id="card_type_button_435" role="button" href="#" aria-haspopup="true" aria-owns="card_type_menu_435" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="0" style="width: 336px;"><span class="ui-selectmenu-status">Visa</span><span class="ui-selectmenu-icon ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s"></span></a>
                        <span class="ui-selectmenu-status">Visa</span>

                        <span class="ui-selectmenu-icon ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s"></span>
                   
                </td>
            </tr>

         </thead>
    </table>
</body>
```

Code

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

from time import sleep
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

#testing on a website that's not public yet, so I won't show the set-up here,but if it's required I can too

cardtype = Select(driver.find_element_by_id("card_type"))
cardtype.select_by_value("Mastercard")
sleep(1)
driver.implicitly_wait(2)


Using Firefox: ElementNotInteractableException:
Element <option> could not be scrolled into view


Using Chrome:
ElementNotVisibleException: element not visible: 
Element is not currently visible and may not be manipulated

# sleep nor implicitly_wait doesn't help too...
```

I also tried just clicking on the box (not using the select tag, I could click on it using the `class="ui-selectmenu"`, but `.send_keys(KEYS.ARROW_DOWN)` doesn't work (gives an `AttributeError`).

Is there a way I can identify the text in an option and click on it without using the Select module? Or is there a way I can get the Select module to work in this case?

Comment: Malformed HTML. The corresponding starting markup is missing for the second `<a>` tag

Comment: @DebanjanB Thanks for noticing! The reason why it's malformed is because I had to manually paste in the first <a> section and the two <span> classes below it (somehow not all the HTML code in the "element" box is shown in the page source?) so I just deleted the second </a> because I couldn't figure out where the other starting <a> should be at...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

thanks so much for the responses! Unfortunately, the problem was really not with wait in this case:/

What did work for me however, was Action Chains. Actions Chains works because you don't have to target an element. So in my post I mentioned I could click the dropdown list, and that down arrows didn't work because it gave an AttributeError. However, that was because I tried targeting the element!

So here's the answer that worked for me:

```
cardtype = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("ui-selectmenu-status")
cardtype.click()

actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.send_keys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN)
actions.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
actions.perform()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use select_by_index. I personally recommend instead of value

```
cardtype = Select(driver.find_element_by_id("card_type"))
cardtype.select_by_index(1)  // 0 - AMEX , 1 - MasterCard and so on
```

Comment: @DebanjanB - Yes, you're correct. My Bad. I will edit it.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code :

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "card_type")))  
cardtype = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('card_type'))
cardtype.select_by_value("Mastercard")  
#OR  

cardtype.select_by_visible_text('MasterCard')
```

Hope this will be helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Unfortunately, it didn't work and after twenty seconds this error appeared  
`raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
TimeoutException`

and this is a form, so the drop-down bar will always be there. Is there a reason why we should use visibility of element_located?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
your_choice=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@id='card_type']/option[@value='Mastercard']")
your_choice.click()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to wait for a while(2 Seconds), Before Select actions. You can use Explicit Wait or sleep. That will solve `Firefox` as well as `Chrome` problem.

**Explicit Wait** :

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "card_type")))
```

**Sleep**:

```
import time
time.sleep( 5 )
```

Answer (score 0):

First click on the dropdown,

```
accountspageobj.select_user_dropdown_on_assign_eventpage().click();
```

Use the below actions class to select the values in a dynamic dropdown.

```
Actions s= new Actions(driver);
s.sendKeys(accountspageobj.select_user_dropdown_on_assign_eventpage(), Keys.chord(Keys.DOWN,Keys.DOWN,Keys.ENTER)).build().perform();
```